# How do I print all the contents present in pagination format without any print preview option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am working on this requirement where I need to display contents using pagination
and print all content at once by a single click on print button.The problem I am facing right now is that when I click on print it creates print preview option for me which I don't want .

I used `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` for pagination.

the pagination looks something like this : (http://plnkr.co/edit/xmjmIId0c9Glh5QH97xz?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my aim was to export the data that I fetched from server and then previewed it in form of pagination. So instead of exporting the whole pagination Template I simply created a new div with the desired layout that I wanted in my pdf file and added css to make it hidden. After that to get rid of my print preview option issue I used this [JQuery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/export-table-json-csv-txt-pdf.html)   .

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with css media queries:

```
@media print {
    /* your specific css for print here, displaying all contents */
}
```

Comment: using media print won't actually resolve print preview issue